# Codeigniter: Ajax Request, global variable in controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I setting the global variable in the __construct();

```
function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();

        //variables
        $this->galleryID = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->productID = $this->uri->segment(4);
}
```

After a selection is made from a dropdown menu I make an ajax request.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/beta/checkout/getCoverSizes',
        data: {
            column: size
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json)
        {
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```

And at this point, simply output the global variable

```
public function getCoverSizes()
    {
        print_r($this->productID);
}
```

Currently nothing is $this->productID is returning 0, and I am positive that it is correct as function index() depends on this variable and is rendering the data correctly. The ajax request does not appear to be accessing the global variable $this->productID.

Comment: There is no any global variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',  // use GET here
        url: '/beta/checkout/getCoverSizes',
        data: {
            column: size
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json)
        {
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$this->uri->segment(3);` for `galleryID` and `$this->uri->segment(4);` for `productID` but the url in `ajax` call doesn't have these parameters  you should pass these ids in ajax call in order to get like

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/beta/checkout/getCoverSizes/1/2',
    //url: '/beta/checkout/getCoverSizes/galleryID/productID',
    data: {
        column: size
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json)
    {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

And in your class i assume you have define the global variables like

```
class checkout extends CI_Controller {
public $galleryID;
public $productID;
// your other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in java-script pass the value js to globle ajax

```
$("#abc").on("change",function(){
var post_data = new FormData();
ajax_request("dashboard/ajax",post_data, response,null);
});
```

and then in JS

```
function ajax_request(URL, request_data, response_function, element){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype:"json",
        url: BASE_URL+URL,
        data: request_data,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            response_function(JSON.parse(result), element);
        },
        error: function() {
            response_function(undefined, element);
        }
    });
}
```